# VMware - guest cannot access server on host (bridged network)

Tags: networking, vmware

I have some guests (Linux and Windows) on a host (Win 7, VMware Workstation 10). The guests are set up to use bridged networking, which seems to work (guests get IP addresses via DHCP from a router, they have internet access, and the host can access servers that are running inside the guests.
BUT the guests can not access a server that is running on the host (although they ARE able to ping the host. The server on the host IS reachable from physical machines in the local network.

Configuration:

Host IP `192.168.0.1/16`
Guest IP `192.168.0.47/16`
This is accessible from host: `http://192.168.0.47:4567`
This works from guest: `ping 192.168.0.1`
This does not work from guest, but from physical machines: `wget http://192.168.0.1`

Can anyone figure this one out, or has any ideas what i could try?

EDIT:
Is this behavior intended? [libvirt documentation](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Guest_can_reach_outside_network,_but_can%27t_reach_host_%28macvtap%29) suggests it could be.

Answer (score 0):

What is the service? Please try to disable windows filewall and please check configuration the service itself.

If I remember correct SNMP and MYSQL services by default accessible ONLY from 127.0.0.1 and you need to change the configuration file of those services to allow access from different IPs.

Comment: The service is a simple file server (hfs). As i wrote it IS reachable from other physical machines in my local network, so i don't think it is a firewall problem.

Comment: When you say IS reachable , do you mean you can ping it or telnet via specific port?  Start wireshark or you host and try to access you service. If you see in wireshark the packets comming into you host from guest, but nothing happend, please read logs of this service, may be you will some errors or other usefull information. If you dont see in witeshark that packets came in - probably firewall is blocking them.

Comment: By reachable i mean that i can reach hfs's webinterface and download files. As i said, this works from all local machines except the virtual one on my host, so it is very unlikely that it is a firewall issue. When i try to access the webinterface from the guest there are no incoming http requests from the guest on the host (captured with wireshark).

Comment: OK - good. Please check all mac addresses - of your host interface and the guests machine's interfaces. Please post all mac addresses and ping from host to guest and after that please run "arp -a" command on host and guests in order to understand that there is no any issue in internal switch of VMware Workstation 10. Please check - may be there is some configuration in VM WS that says to deny internal communication.

Comment: Host Mac: 30-85-...-a7; 
Guest Mac: 00:0c:..:0f; 
Host arp output:  192.168.0.47          00-0c-..-0f     dynamic; 
Guest arp output: (192.168.0.1) at 30:85:...:a7; 
There does not seem to be a setting to deny internal communication, not in the virtual network editor, not in vmware preferences and not in vm preferences either.

Comment: Please try to create another simple guest VM and telnet to host with specific port.

Comment: From guest:
telnet 192.168.0.1 80
Trying 192.168.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out. From the second guest same problem: hfs webinterface on host is not reachable as soon as i enable bridged networking.

Comment: try to connect guest VM to some other network card - for exaplme - HOST ONLY - and configure the guest network card to be in the same subnet.

Comment: With host-only networking or NAT networking the webinterface on the host is reachable from the guest. As soon as i switch the vm network card to bridged networking its not anymore.

Comment: if it very important for you - try to install different version of VM WS or try to install vmplayer. if it is will not help  - try to reinstall your host OS.

Comment: The last this that I can think about  is try to create additional NIC at you guest and try to connect via this interface. Please be sure that VM WS provide a new mac address to this new NIC and after creation please be sure that this MAC address is visible from host.

Can you please try to configure your service to work on diffent port - for example 8080 and please try to telnet it via port 8080

Comment: It's important to me, but more out of curiosity. I just find it hard to understand why i can ping, but not access via browser.
Different port gives the same (telnet and other) results as before.
Instead of an additional NIC in the guest i use another workaround: i have a dyndns domain name and use that to access the server on the host from the guest (only small textfiles so speed is not an issue).